# swift: How to load photos from photo library without using UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, photo

I am using swift to load images from photo library. I know that I can use UIImagePickerController to let user to choose the images from camera roll but I want to access photos without user actions. For example, I want to read a series of photos which are from camera roll and put them in a photo slide to show them one by one. How can I access these photos without  UIImagePickerController?

Comment: Use the Photos framework: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios//documentation/Photos/Reference/Photos_Framework/index.html

Comment: The link you provided is broken. Please make sure any links are and remain active.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access photo library using [Photos](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios//documentation/Photos/Reference/Photos_Framework/index.html#other) framework(for iOS 8+). Take a look at [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UsingPhotosFramework/Introduction/Intro.html) example. In AAPLRootListViewController's code if awakeFromNib method you can see how to create PHFetchResult object to retrieve specific photos data. Then, in AAPLAssetGridViewController, PHAsset objects(from PHFetchResult) are used for retrieving actual image data. Take a look at method

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

The code is written in Objective-C rather than Swift, but you could do the same using Swift. Ask questions if any.

Comment: Would be nice if you can give a swift implementation since the question is tagged in Swift.