# Swift - How to fetch videos from camera roll and display them in UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, video, uicollectionview

I want to load all camera roll videos in UICollectionView along with their duration (same way, the videos are shown in camera roll). How to do so ?
I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35115117/swift-how-to-load-photos-from-photo-library-without-using-uiimagepickercontroll) link. But they showed their videos like images.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [swift: How to load photos from photo library without using UIImagePickerController?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35115117/swift-how-to-load-photos-from-photo-library-without-using-uiimagepickercontroll)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
// get all videos from Photos library you need to import Photos framework
var photos: PHFetchResult<PHAsset>! // user photos array in collectionView for disaplying video thumnail
func getAssetFromPhoto() {
    let options = PHFetchOptions()
    options.sortDescriptors = [ NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: true) ]
    options.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType = %d", PHAssetMediaType.video.rawValue)
    photos = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: options)
    print(photos)
    photoCollectionView.reloadData() // reload your collectionView
}

// For displaying thumnait image and video dutation
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "photoCell", for: indexPath) as! PhotoCollectionViewCell
    let asset = photos!.object(at: indexPath.row)
    let width: CGFloat = 150
    let height: CGFloat = 150
    let size = CGSize(width:width, height:height)
    PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: size, contentMode: PHImageContentMode.aspectFill, options: nil) { (image, userInfo) -> Void in

        self.photoImageView.image = image
        self.lblVideoTime.text = String(format: "%02d:%02d",Int((asset.duration / 60)),Int(asset.duration) % 60)

    }
    return cell
}
```

- Note : Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description - > I need you photos library add this key into info.plist file

Comment: can you please upload the full class ? @Yogesh Makwana

Comment: I didn't get the second portion of your code...where to write that and the function **getAssetFromPhoto()**, should I call it in viewDidLoad() method ?

Comment: yes  getAssetFromPhoto() call in  viewDidLoad() and for displaying video thumnail : func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
    }

Comment: can you please upload the **func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell { }**
for me it is tough to understand :(

Comment: I updated answer, please try it

Comment: thanx... it worked :)

Comment: I need to get the video URL when user select a UICollectionView cell. What should I write in **func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) { }** ? Can you please help me on that?

Comment: i need to have a collection view where , images and videos all are mixed .
how can we do it . i know how to do with only images or videos .

how can we combine both ?

Comment: options.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType = %d && mediaType = %d”, PHAssetMediaType.video.rawValue,PHAssetMediaType.image.rawValue)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the photos framework that apple has prebuilt into Xcode. The answer to this question is already filled out here:

[swift: How to load photos from photo library without using UIImagePickerController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35115117/swift-how-to-load-photos-from-photo-library-without-using-uiimagepickercontroll)

The photos framework created by apple:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios//documentation/Photos/Reference/Photos_Framework/index.html

To add a video you can use a UIImagePickerCrollerSourceType:

```
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
```

Comment: videos are look like images...there is no duration there.

Comment: You want show videos, not images, right?

Comment: yes...i just want to load the videos