# Is it mandatory to add NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription in info.plist?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I am not using UIImagePicker in my app and not accessing the Photo Library. I  got a mail regarding add NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription in info.plist file.

I have following questions

How to confirm my project accessing the photo library?

I already searched UIImagePicker in my project and did't get any result.

Is it mandatory to add NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription in info.plist while i am not accessing the photo library?

Can any one help to find it out .

Thanks

Comment: It's not mandatory. Some of your libraries might use it without your knowledge.

Comment: I searched for "UIImagePicker" but did't get any result. How to find which library using it?

Comment: @Ranjan were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

**UIImagePicker**

An image picker controller manages user interactions and delivers the results of those interactions to a delegate object. The role and appearance of an image picker controller depend on the source type you assign to it before you present it.

whenever you used UIImagePicker, you have to give permission for that particular application

There is a list of all Cocoa Keys that you can specify in your Info.plist file:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html

(Xcode target -> Info -> Custom iOS Target Properties)

iOS already required permissions to access microphone, camera, and media library earlier (iOS6, iOS7), but since iOS10 the apps will crash if you don't provide the description why you are asking for the permission.

**UPDATE**:

Summary of all privacy keys (with example description): [image]

[Useful Link](https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2016/09/infoplist-privacy-settings-in-ios-10.html)

Answer (score 0):

You only have to add this key-value pair to your info.plist if you are actually accessing the photos any way. If it's not added the app is going to crash.
Check if any of your added dependencies using UIImagePicker.

Comment: I searched for "UIImagePicker" but did't get any result. How to find which library using it?

Comment: When you press cmd+shit+F you can change the search's scope, set it the widest

Answer (score -1):

**No** it's not mandatory to add `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` key in **info.plist**. If your App is not using accessing photo from library/gallery then you should remove it. But as **"@Bence Pattogato"** said if Your app accessing photo from library/gallery and there is no key added in info.plist then it will be crash.

For your information below are different keys that required to add **info.plist** if you accessing relevant features according to camera/photo library.

1) `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` : This key lets you describe the reason your app accesses the user’s photo library. When the system prompts the user to allow access, this string is displayed as part of the alert.

2) `NSCameraUsageDescription` :  describes the reason that the app (including an iMessage app) accesses the device’s camera. When the system prompts the user to allow access, this string is displayed as part of the alert.

3) `NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription` : ***(New in iOS 11)*** This key lets you describe the reason your app seeks write-only access to the user’s photo library. When the system prompts the user to allow access, this string is displayed as part of the alert.

[Above information get from this Appel official link.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW73)

Comment: I searched for "UIImagePicker" but did't get any result. How to find which library using it?

Comment: Look at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44877195/swift-3-load-photos-from-photos-camera-roll-without-using-uiimagepickercontroll  are you using that?