# Swift: Load Photos images into app

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, photos

I have an app which shows a screensaver when it detects that there is no user action. Currently, it is working as the images for the screensaver are preloaded into the app.

But ultimately I want the screensaver to access and show the images inside Photos as we would save promotion images into Photos and these images are subjected to frequent changes.

I am stuck and do not know how to proceed to access and read images from Photos.

Please help. :(

```
import UIKit
import Photos

class ScreenSaverViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var ssImage: UIImageView!

    var timer = Timer()
    var count = 0

    var arrayPhoto: [UIImage] = [
        UIImage(named:"0.jpg")!,
        UIImage(named:"1.jpg")!,
        UIImage(named:"2.jpg")!,
        UIImage(named:"3.jpg")!
    ]

    var images = [PHAsset]()

    func nextImage() {
         let currentIndex = arrayPhoto.index(of: ssImage.image ?? UIImage()) ?? -1

         var nextIndex = currentIndex + 1

         nextIndex = arrayPhoto.indices.contains(nextIndex) ? nextIndex : 0

         UIView.transition(with: ssImage, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: { self.ssImage.image = self.arrayPhoto[nextIndex] }, completion: nil)


    }

    func scheduledTimer(){
         timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: (#selector(nextImage)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
         count = 1
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         if count == 0 {
              ssImage.image = UIImage(named: "0.jpg")
         }
         scheduledTimer()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
         super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
         timer.invalidate()
         self.dismiss(animated: true, completed: nil)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly use Photos framework. I encourage you to read documentation first: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos

Anyway, to get images, you can do it like this:

```
func getImages() {
    let assets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: PHAssetMediaType.image, options: nil)
    assets.enumerateObjects({ (object, count, stop) in
        self.images.append(object)
    })

    //In order to get latest image first, we just reverse the array
    images.reverse() 
}
```

Credits: [Swift 3: Load photos from Photos/Camera Roll without using UIImagePickerController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44877195/swift-3-load-photos-from-photos-camera-roll-without-using-uiimagepickercontroll)

Comment: Thanks. How do I then transit to the next image as previously I was calling arrayPhoto.index(of: ssImage.image ?? UIImage()) ?? -1 where arrayPhoto was the declaration of the images preloaded.

Comment: @Spiral1ng Keep track of current `PHAsset` shown and when apply the same logic as before to get next one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should provide a button in your app, tapping on which will open `UIImagePickerController` with source type `.photos`. The user of the app can select the images he wish should be included in the screen saver.

Implement the protocols `UIImagePickerController` & `UINavigationControllerDelegate`, particularly the function `func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])` in which you can access the selected images. You may then save these images to the Documents folder of your app and use them while showing the screen saver.

Comment: I want to have zero user intervention as the previous app using swift 2 was built this way, but the ALAssetsLibrary has since deprecated.

Comment: Apple is not a very big supporter of giving the user's personal stuff's access to the developer without the user's permission. So I think you will have to ask the user before using his images as screensaver. This might be the reason behind deprecating ALAssetsLibrary.